# Image compression after selecting an image from gallery into an ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have been searching image compression and i found this useful link a whatsapp like compression example http://grishma102.blogspot.ug/2016/03/image-compression-in-android.html and also read different posts such as [How whatsapp/Instagram or other compresses the image before uploading it to server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34663004/how-whatsapp-instagram-or-other-compresses-the-image-before-uploading-it-to-serv)  on this same issue , but i have failed to achieve what i want .

**My achievemnet is :-**

1. I want when i select an image from the gallery, it attaches it's self on an ImageView when it's already compressed.

***This is how i was doing it***

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data == null) {
            //showError("Failed to open picture!");
            return;
        }
        try {

            imageUri = data.getData();
            compressImage(imageUri.toString());
            Picasso.with(c).load(imageUri).fit().into(imageSelect);


        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And of course the  `compressImage()` method  , is as below i got it from the links i have posted,

```
  public static String compressImage(String imagePath) {
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

    int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
    int actualWidth = options.outWidth;

    float imgRatio = (float) actualWidth / (float) actualHeight;
    float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

    if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
        if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
            imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
            actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
            actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
        } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
            actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
            actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
        } else {
            actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
        }
    }
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inDither = false;
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    options.inInputShareable = true;
    options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];
    try {
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
    float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
    float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
    float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;
    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
    canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));
    if (bmp != null) {
        bmp.recycle();
    }
    ExifInterface exif;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (orientation == 6) {
            matrix.postRotate(90);
        } else if (orientation == 3) {
            matrix.postRotate(180);
        } else if (orientation == 8) {
            matrix.postRotate(270);
        }
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    String filepath = getFilename();
    try {
        //new File(imageFilePath).delete();
        out = new FileOutputStream(filepath);

        //write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by filename.
        scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return filepath;
}

public static String getFilename() {
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/ImageCompApp/Images");

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
    }

    String mImageName = "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg";
    String uriString = (mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + mImageName);
    return uriString;
}

public static void hideKeyboard(Activity context) {
    try {
        if (context == null) return;
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(context.getWindow().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

***But its not working the way am expecting it , where am i wrong please***

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
 public String compressImage(String imageUri) {

        String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

//      by setting this field as true, the actual bitmap pixels are not loaded in the memory. Just the bounds are loaded. If
//      you try the use the bitmap here, you will get null.
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
        int actualWidth = options.outWidth;

//      max Height and width values of the compressed image is taken as 816x612

        float maxHeight = 500.0f;
        float maxWidth = 500.0f;
        float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
        float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

//      width and height values are set maintaining the aspect ratio of the image

        if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
            if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
            } else {
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

            }
        }

//      setting inSampleSize value allows to load a scaled down version of the original image

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);

//      inJustDecodeBounds set to false to load the actual bitmap
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

//      this options allow android to claim the bitmap memory if it runs low on memory
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inInputShareable = true;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

        try {
//          load the bitmap from its path
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();

        }
        try {
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
        float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
        float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
        float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

//      check the rotation of the image and display it properly
        ExifInterface exif;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            }
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                    scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                    true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FileOutputStream out = null;
        String filename = getFilename();
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(filename);

//          write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by filename.
            scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return filename;

    }

    public String getFilename() {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "MyFolder/Images");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        String uriSting = (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        return uriSting;

    }

    private String getRealPathFromURI(String contentURI) {
        Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(contentURI);
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return contentUri.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    }

    public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }
        final float totalPixels = width * height;
        final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;
        while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
            inSampleSize++;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

the above code is used to reduce the size of images with maintaining the aspect ratio.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424942/decrease-image-size-without-losing-its-quality-in-android)

hope it helps u..

Comment: Thanks @rafsanahmad , but does it maintain the image quality , thats my main essence

Comment: Beacuse what i want is, after attachin the image into the inageView i send it to the server when it's already compressed

Comment: so u want to resize and scale the bitmap without losing it's quality...?

Comment: yeah , something like whatsapp like compressing method, i know that the image loses quality , but whatsapp like compression makes a little change in losing quality , even eyes can't notice it

Comment: @ rafsanahmad007  , thanks for the edit , but that's the method am already using , please read my question very well . Thanks

Comment: So i dont know if the way i was attaching  `compressImage()`  is correct in the `onActivityResult()` method

Comment: did u catch any exception in onActivity result?

Comment: `android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 16817268 bytes`, this is what am seeing